# ERROR The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-locust-role associated with the environment does not exist

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, locust

I'm trying to create my environment with elastic beanstalk and locust but i can't pass this part

```
Printing Status:
2023-05-05 18:02:19    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2023-05-05 18:02:21    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-019560785629 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2023-05-05 18:05:29    ERROR   The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-locust-role associated with the environment does not exist.
2023-05-05 18:05:29    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.
                                
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to launch environment.
```

My code is this

`eb create --instance_type t2.micro --scale 1 --envvars TARGET_URL=https://www.pacifiko.com/ -ip aws-elasticbeanstalk-locust-role`

I did an IAM user and role in AWS and the rest in code. This are my screenshots of the policys and some error in the GUI of ElasticBeanstalk and EC2 Management

[IAM Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrLTQ.png)

[Permissions policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBZX5.png)

[Elasticbeanstalk dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6lZo.png)

[Events in elastickbeanstalk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE7wQ.png)

[Inside configuration of the environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTeB2.png)

I need to see the Locust GUI after the process is done

Comment: I've never used Elastic Beanstalk and am unfamiliar with your tool, but your command has an EC2 Instance type and your error mentioned Instance Profiles.  An Instance Profile is an abstraction wrapped around an IAM Role; did you create one for your Role?

Comment: Yes! I did create a Role and a Profile with the same name